# Jsoup parsing error

Tags: android, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

I get the following error (at the "for (Element div : divs)" part):

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type org.jsoup.nodes.Element to android.sax.Element
```

With the following code:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("www.example.com").get();
    Elements divs = doc.select("div#heading");
    for (Element div : divs)
    {
        System.out.println(div.text());
    }
```

and the following imports:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.sax.Element;
import android.view.Menu;
```

How can I fix this>

Answer (score 0):

`android.sax.Element` is the wrong import --> `org.jsoup.nodes.Element`

**Edit**

Here's my test of your code (no exceptionhandling done here!):

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.tip.it/runescape").get();
        Elements divs = doc.select("div[class=heading]");

        for( Element div : divs )
        {
            System.out.println(div.text());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do that I get another error
    Unhandled exception type IOException android

Comment: please post some more informations (eg. full exception with stacktrace and / or sourcecode). Do you use `android.sax.Element` somewhere else in your classfile?

Comment: No I don't use android.sax.Element anywhere else I took that out.
It's showing the error for "Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com").get();"

Comment: Ah, ok. You have to insert the protocol: using `http://www.example.com` instead should solve your problem

Comment: No sorry I still get that problem.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the exception please?

Comment: If you have a logfile of your program you can find it there, or post the output of your IDE. Where can you see the IOException (maybe you can post the new exception like the one from first post) ? Btw. did you try to run only the code listed above? I've put it into a simple main-method and ran it without any problems.

Comment: In the Error log it says "An exception stack trace is not available." 
My code atm is:
http://pastebin.com/MZinD0Xa
and the error is: "Unhandled exception type IOException"
Which is referring to "Jsoup.connect("http://www.tip.it/runescape").get();"

Comment: Hmmm ... i tested the Jsoup part of your `onCreate()` Method on pc --> works (but btw. use `doc.select("div[class=heading]")`). Here in the comments you posted `tip.it...` as url, but in your paste you have `http://tip.it`. did you run this one - remember, protocol is required here?

Comment: I changed the doc.select to    Elements divs = doc.select("div[class=heading]"); It still doesn't work.
I do have the http:// but stackoverflow took it out.

Comment: Strange! Does android require any connection or firewall settings? It's already connected to the internet, isn't it?

Comment: No it doesn't need any special connection or anything. I even removed the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> from the manifest file and still nothing
You said you tried my code and it worked for you?

Comment: Yes, but from a pc. Get the selected value, no exception.

Comment: Can you say what you did from start until you got that value? It has to be something small

Comment: No sorry when I run that I get the following in the console log http://pastebin.com/qRPp7Mv3

Comment: Did you run the content of the method or the whole class? I guess Android doesn't use the `Main` class / method. However, your code seems to ok. Maybe its a good idea to run your jsoup code from another thread than the UI one. Take a look at [AsyncTask documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#AsyncTask)